# In IBM SCRIPT/VS, what does DSM stand for in macros DSMFIG, DSMLIST

Tags: ibm

In (S)GML ancestor's IBM SCRIPT/VS, what does DSM stand for in macros DSMFIG, DSMLIST... ?

Comment: please add more details to your post. It is difficult to know what you're asking with proper context.

Comment: See, for example, [the IBM SCRIPT/VS programmer’s guide](https://archive.org/details/bitsavers_ibm370DCFSpositionFacilitySCRIPTVSTextProgrammersG_17539665).

Comment: I understand what you're asking. However, some more details would be nice; the AD is FTH for the A(R|PA).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> what does DSM stand for in macros

In principle nothing. It's "just" a string used to mark all (well, most) APF (*Application Processing Function*) that are part of the system. IBM provides in no place a meaningful interpretation.

In an informal way I was given ***D**ocument **S**tructure **M**acro* as an explanation ... but that was *quite* a long time ago and I doubt that there will be any reference anywhere.

Like so often it's a naming convention to manage symbols of different origin within a single name space. This continues within the DSM macros as:

- `DSM@` marking all attribute handling macros
- `DSM#` indicating internal macros that get called by others or the profile
- `DSME` for end tag macros
- Any other `DSM` Macro will handle one or more start tags

---

BTW, as so often with IBM, names aren't as sharply defined as one may assume. Depending on context the language is [SCRIPT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SCRIPT_(markup)) or [Generalized Markup Language](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_Generalized_Markup_Language) (GML).

SCRIPT defines a set of very basic, serially processed output formatting commands to be embedded in text, with each command starting a new line (*1). SCRIPT/VS is one of many extensions, like SCRIPT/370 before. It offered extensions to support IBM's 3800 laser printer. It was also ported to the PC, and gained thus some audience.

GML on the other hand is a format using a tag based system, much like today's SGML (or HTML). It uses start and end tags, encapsulated between a colon (`:`) and a period (`.`), much like the `<` and `>` in HTML. Except, GML doesn't really exist at all. What exists is the GML Starter Set, a set of macros that handle the conversion of block based encoding into the serial format of SCRIPT.

Oh, and then there is EasyScript - a simplified GML version, that gets directly interpreted with other SCRIPT  commands.

Not to mention that IBM did create many dialects or extensions like ISIL, the ***I**nformation **S**tructure **I**dentification **L**anguage*, a GML extension/version used to write most of their manuals.

Another variant is *Bookmaster* which as well enriches GML for publishing purpose, here with regards to modern printers and graphic displays to support more complex and visually appealing layouts.

Together with *Bookmanager* it creates a PDF like environment to render such documents on graphic devices. It comes with a server product to manage libraries of  ... well, E-Books :))

Sometimes it seems there isn't anything that IBM didn't develop ahead of time just to not be able to make it standard later on when the world was ready.

---

*1 - SCRIPT itself is close related to [RUNOFF](http://web.mit.edu/multics-history/source/Multics/doc/info_segments/runoff.info) - better known due it's unix clone `roff` :)

Comment: I didn't expect such a comprehensive answer! Thank you!

Comment: @Greg82 You're wellcome. This is RC.SE, we like a holistic answer as much as a well formed question (hint).